# Control traffic on layer2 switch - All traffic should be "routed" to transparent firewall

Tags: firewall

I am stucked with this problem since a view days.

I would like to deploy a transparent firewall between my users and the default gateway. For different reasons, the firewall cannot be deployed in-line between users and the default gateway but has to be physically connected to the switch.

[image: Illustration]

**Question:**
What switching technique would you recommend to forcing the traffic through the firewall. Is this even possible?

Thank you for you support

Comment: What are the "different reasons"?  There are firewalls that can act like L-2 bridges rather than L-3 routers, and therefore don't require changes to IP addressing plans.

Comment: you are right and it exactly the kind of firewall I want to use, but still you would have to deploy the firewall between the switch and the DG, ie in-line? In my case, re-cabling is not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two VLANS on your switch (100 and 200). All users go in vlan 100. Your gateway connects to vlan 200.  Your firewall connects to both vlans.